# Image that follows mouse

Tags: javascript, mouse

I'm trying to create a zoomed visual box with the possibility to move the visual on the Y avis from top to bottom with the mouse following.

My problem is that I need to limit the navigation to the top and the bottom of the visual to avoid white spaces over and below the image while navigate with the mouse to the extremes.

Here is my code :

HTML

```
<div class="follower-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?image=1083" class="follower-image" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.follower-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.follower-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

JS

```
var mouse = { x:0, y:0 };
var image_position = { x:0, y:0 };

// Get mouse position
function getMouse(e){
    mouse.x = e.clientX || e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY || e.pageY;
}

$('.follower-container').mousemove(function(e){
        getMouse(e);
});

// Move visual regarding mouse position
function moveImage(){
    var distY = mouse.y - image_position.y;
    image_position.y += distY/5;

    $('.follower-image').css({
        'top': image_position.y + "px"
    });
}

setInterval(moveImage, 20);
```

My jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/balix/hc2atzun/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` to restrict the position to a certain range.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min

`Math.max()` will return the *larger* of the two passed numbers:

```
Math.max(0, 100); // 100
Math.max(12, 5); // 12
```

`Math.min()` will return the *smaller* of the two passed numbers:

```
Math.min(0, 100); // 0
Math.min(12, 5); // 5
```

By combining them, you can restrict a given number to be within a range. If it is outside of the range, it will max out (or min out) at the ends of the range:

```
function keepInRange(n, minNum, maxNum) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(minNum, n), maxNum);
}
keepInRange(-12, 0, 100); // 0
keepInRange(30, 0, 100); // 30
keepInRange(777, 0, 100); // 100
```

Now, you just need to figure out the math behind what number range to keep your `top` CSS value inside of. I highly, *highly* recommend that you give a go at that yourself.

If you really can't figure out the solution on your own, here it is for this case: https://jsfiddle.net/oeynjcpL/

Comment: Great help, thanks a lot. I didn't know these methods, I will check this out in details.

Answer (score 0):

Animation gets even better with requestAnimationFrame ;)

```
var mouse = { x:0, y:0 };
var image_position = { x:0, y:0 };

// Get mouse position
function getMouse(e){
    mouse.x = e.clientX || e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY || e.pageY;
}

$('.follower-container').mousemove(function(e){
    getMouse(e);
});

// Returns number n if is inside of minNum and maxNum range
// Otherwise returns minNum or maxNum
function keepInRange(n, minNum, maxNum) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(minNum, n), maxNum);
}

// Move visual regarding mouse position
function moveImage(){
    var distY = mouse.y - image_position.y;
    image_position.y += distY/5;
    // minHeight is the containing element's height minus half the height of the image
    var minHeight = $('.follower-container').height() - $('.follower-image').height() / 2;
    // maxHeight is half the height of the image
    var maxHeight = $('.follower-image').height() / 2;

    $('.follower-image').css({
        'top': keepInRange(image_position.y, minHeight, maxHeight) + "px"
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(moveImage);
}

requestAnimationFrame(moveImage);
```